# Is the small signal model of a BJT amplifier valid for any sinusoidal signal?

Tags: amplifier, bjt

According to the small signal model, a CE amplifier amplifies only the signal component of the input voltage that causes small perturbations around the operating point. My question is if we put say a > 1 V sinusoidal signal on the base terminal, then wouldn't the perturbations around the Q point be much larger than the mV range the small signal model requires? How does the transistor amplify this if this is the case?

Comment: There's a reason it's called the "small signal" model. The limitation of the model is right there in the name. It won't always be so convenient.

Comment: [All models are wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does the transistor amplify this if this is the case?

The transistor doesn't care much about human ideas of what it ought to do. It just does it. The models are ideas in human brains that make it easier for humans to understand nature.

When the signal is large, the small signal model doesn't apply, because it is - *as the name implies* - a **small** signal model :)

The "small signal" name is convenient but not fully descriptive: we can definitely set up the transistor in operating conditions such that the small-signal model will work for signals much larger than "mV range". You'll need either high operating voltages and fairly large resistances, or external current sources or cascode configurations, and negative or feed-forward feedback helps too.

Discrete power audio amplifiers do their best to operate the transistors such that they are quite linear even with signal amplitudes of tens of volts. With global negative feedback, these transistors end up operating almost exactly how the small signal model predicts, at power levels of tens, hundreds, or even thousands of Watts. Those circuits aren't very simple anymore, but the model applies - because the desired behavior is linear in spite of high signal amplitudes and currents.

If you're actually asking what model will work for signals larger than the small signal model can handle in a given circuit? The next "better" model that is meant to work with larger signals in usual amplifying transistor configurations found in textbooks is the Ebers-Moll model. As the conditions of use of the transistor become more "complex", i.e. stray farther away from textbooks and simple circuits, or if we need higher accuracy that the simplest models provide, even the Ebers-Moll model becomes inadequate, and more advanced/higher-fidelity models are needed.

The modern models of transistors used in circuit simulation ("SPICE" and similar tools) are complex enough that sizable monographs describe their derivation and use, and many tens of parameters are needed to model the real device.

The state of the art 50 years ago (mid-1970s) was already advanced enough that Ian Getreu's "Modeling The Bipolar Transistor" book is about 250 pages long. The same depth of coverage of a modern model would be easily 4x as long.

That's pretty much the case with any sort of an engineering model. In mechanics of materials, linear elasticity is the "small deflection model", beyond that you end up with various models of non-linear elasticity, plasticity, fracture mechanics, and so on.

Even those have finite application ranges. If you were to slam a relativistic (very, very fast or energetic) baseball into a chunk of steel, none of the usual engineering models will work - you'll need quantum-electrodynamical models :)

Comment: +1 for the xkcd reference: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Comment: @TimWilliams Hit by pitch.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question: Yes and no.

Let me explain: Sometimes - in particular for linear(ized) small-circuit circuit simulations - we are using an ac input signal of 1V. This is convenient because in this case the output signal is identical to the gain of the circuit.

Question: Is this OK for such a small-signal analysis?

Answer: Yes - because "small signal" does not mean that the input sgnal must be as small as possible. In fact, the input signal can be as large as you want - but from the simulator it is treated as if it were a small signal (due to the linearized model).

But the user should know that - in the real world - the result applies to "small-signals" only. And in this respect "small" means: So small that the errors (non-linearities) are within acceptable limits (application dependent).

Answer (score 1):

When small-signal analysis fails -- use large signal analysis, of course :)

Unfortunately, that doesn't mean very much.  There are some standard approaches that work in various special cases, but there of course cannot be a general solution -- nonlinear dynamical systems are Turing complete (that is, in the worst general case, you'd have to solve the halting problem: a paradox).

For well-behaved amplifiers, there is load-pull analysis, harmonic balance analysis and others.  For (quasi)-periodic systems, there is  periodic steady-state (PSS) analysis.  For everything else, there's just plain old grindwork -- numerical integration (SPICE for example).

In some cases, we can expand the small-signal analysis to simply include harmonics of a nonlinear transfer function (e.g. the exponential of the Ebers-Moll equation); but in others, the nonlinearity affects dynamics (e.g., the incremental base resistance of a BJT is proportional to current, and thus the Cbe pole varies), and the problem might only reasonably be expressed in a differential equation (which is now neither linear nor time-invariant).

Some systems, despite being extremely nonlinear (massive incremental gain, hysteresis, 100s of harmonics being relevant), can be reduced to very simple forms, give or take various assumptions and approximations.  PSS is a popular method to use in switching power supply design, and some schemes can even be reduced all the way to an average-mode equivalent (e.g. the standard buck/boost/etc. topologies in DCM or CCM).

More generally, any analyses discovered in the study of differential equations, can be applied to any physical system equivalent to them.  The challenge of course is finding such pairings -- or close enough pairings that the analysis can be fruitfully modified to match, or where the physical system can be mutated to match the equation.

And even when an approximate solution isn't available, a statistical one may be -- nonlinear dynamical systems are in the domain of chaos theory.  There can be pockets of stability within an overall chaotic system, as long as you don't need to predict too far in the future (Lyapunov time), or perhaps you're only interested in the locus the system is likely to reach (e.g. bounded or probable range for given setpoint, etc.), rather than the detailed dynamics.

Afraid I don't have any worked examples, as I don't use these myself -- I don't do RF amplifier design for example -- but these are some examples I am aware of, and you can research them further for ideas.

Comment: I don't think actual electronic circuit analysis could ever involve the halting problem because that problem is about determining whether something goes on forever or eventually stops, while we only care about the behaviour in a certain time window. If our amplifier doesn't produce the requested output voltage within a few milliseconds, we can reject it. If a circuit exhibits complex behaviour, we simply label it "chaotic" and move on (see Chua's circuit) - we don't try to predict what the chaos eventually leads to.

Comment: Computers are electronic circuits, the analysis of which has led to, well -- *gestures vaguely*. While we can pretty easily categorize simple circuits like amplifiers, the general space of circuit analysis as a whole, necessarily includes the entirety of computer science, therefore I would be remiss not to mention it.